# how to use the for loop in html template

Tags: html, templates

Have no idea how to add loop to the template.
can someone make an example to show the syntax of how to use the for loop to the template?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>This page was generated from a template</title>
</head>
<body>

{{loop}}
<h6>{{content_from_data_structure}}</h6>
{{end_loop}}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a markup language, you cant create object or loop in it. You can use PHP or Javascript to create and insert objects to HTML.

With PHP its something like this;

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php 
            for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) 
            {
                echo "<h1>The number is: $x</h1>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

With Javascript;

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="insertHere"></div>
        <script>
            var text = "";
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            {
                text += "<h1>The number is: " + i.toString() + "<br>";
            }
            document.getElementById("insertHere").innerHTML = text;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```